# How to turn a lists of lists into one list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of words that went into a tokenizier and came out like so:

[[0], [97], [153]]

I want to go from that list into:

[0, 97, 153]

How would I do that?

Comment: `new = [x[0] for x in old_array]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [[0], [97], [153]]
[x[0] for x in l]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.